# VBA Incorrect parameter using 7z with command

Tags: excel, vba, parameters, directory, 7zip

I want to compress a folder with 7z using a macro but when I add the parameters to the command line the program show me an error with them (it's in Spanish but I suppose that the correct translation is "Incorrect parameter").

> System error: El parámetro no es correcto.

There is the subroutine:

```
Sub ZipDLEFolder()

Dim strCommand As String
Dim z7Path As String
Dim fnDestination As String
Dim source As String

z7Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J5")
fnDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J6")
source = Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D6") & Chr(34)
strCommand = z7Path & " a -tzip " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fnDestination & Chr(34) & " " & source & "-m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa"

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J23") = strCommand
Shell strCommand, 1
```

The parameters are important to make the smallest version of the file for using it in an email. In the previous version I used a .bat file and works fine with this:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Set variable
set "destiny=%~dp0folder.7z"
set "source=%~dp0\folder"

Rem compress the file
c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe a -t7z %destiny% %source% -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing in your command line after the source:

```
strCommand = z7Path & " a -tzip " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fnDestination & Chr(34) & " " & source & " -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But the subroutine has the same behavior with the missing space.

Comment: Is this "c:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "H:\folder.7z" "H:\folder" -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa